# express.js pass database query result to template

Tags: node.js, express

Here is the route function:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    var mysql = require('mysql')
    var connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host: 'localhost',
        user: 'root',
        password: 'Abcd1234',
        database: 'mtest'
    });

    connection.connect()
    global.products = "abc"

    connection.query('SELECT name from catalog_product_flat_1', function (err, rows, fields) {
        if (err) throw err
        global.products = rows[0].name;
    })

    connection.end()
    console.log('Product is: ', products)
    res.render(
        'product', { products: global.products, title: 'abc' }
    );
});

module.exports = router;
```

No matter how i can't assign the query result to products,  products: global.products is eventually undefined , anyone know how to do that?

Comment: are you not getting `global.products` as `abc`, at first run or is it `undefined`?

Comment: also, why do you want to save the query result to the `globals`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

`connection.query` is an asynchronous method, move your rendering logic inside the function. Try this,

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
    var mysql = require('mysql')
    var connection = mysql.createConnection({
        host: 'localhost',
        user: 'root',
        password: 'Abcd1234',
        database: 'mtest'
    });

    connection.connect()

    connection.query('SELECT name from catalog_product_flat_1', function (err, rows, fields) {
        if (err) throw err
        let products = rows[0].name;

        console.log('Product is: ', products)

        res.render(
            'product', { products: global.products, title: 'abc' }
        );

        connection.end()
    })
});

module.exports = router;
```

And also as @Raghav Garg Mentioned below, connecting to the database on each request may not be ideal (or may be ideal if this request does not get called much, so you don't want to keep the connection alive with the database, depend on your requirements). But I believe that is  another performance optimization which is not relevant to your question.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the asynchronous programming. Your code could be written like:

```
var express = require('express');
var mysql = require('mysql')

var router = express.Router();

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
  host: 'localhost',
  user: 'root',
  password: 'Abcd1234',
  database: 'mtest'
}).connect();

/* GET users listing. */
router.get('/', function (req, res, next) {
  connection.query('SELECT name from catalog_product_flat_1', function (err, rows, fields) {
    if (err) throw err
    res.render('product', { products: rows, title: 'abc' });
  });
});

process.on('SIGTERM', () => {
  console.info('SIGTERM signal received.');
  connection.end()
});

module.exports = router;
```

In the above code,

- DB connection: we will not connect to our db again and again for every route hit, we will create a single connection and will use it all over the app for any db operation.
- DB operation: we will have to wait for the operation to complete and will send the response once we will get the result. (async nature)
- exiting process: now since we are using single connection all over the app, once our process is exiting we will gracefully close the connection to our db.

Please read more about js asynchronous nature and how to deal with it. You currently using `callbacks`, but now we have more ways like `promises` and `async/await`. https://medium.com/@tkssharma/writing-neat-asynchronous-node-js-code-with-promises-async-await-fa8d8b0bcd7c